# How can I do a write run-time type-check expression using Flow type?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Suppose I have two types defined in Flow:

```
type A = {
  x : string; 
};

type B = {
  y : string; 
};
```

Now I have a function `f` like this:

```
const f = (o : A | B) : string => {
  if (o isa A) { // Not real code
    return o.x;
  }
  return o.y;
};
```

How do I implement `o isa A`?

I want to create an expression that checks an object against a Flow type-definition at run-time.

The compiled code might look like this:

```
const f = o => {
  if (typeof(o.x) !== 'undefined') {
    return o.x;
  }
  return o.y;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two primary issues here.

1. Nothing says a `B`-typed object can't have a `x` property too, just like `A`, and same for the inverse.
2. Flow isn't quite smart enough to differentiate object types this way.

For the first point, to be clear, your existing definition is fine with

```
var o: B = {
  x: 45,
  y: "string",
};
```

because `{ y: string }` means "an object where `y` is a `string`", not "an object with *only* a `y` that is a `string`."

To get the behavior you are expecting, you'd need to use Flow's [Exact Object Syntax](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types) as

```
type A = {|
  x : string; 
|};

type B = {|
  y : string; 
|};
```

Now to the second point, the easiest approach is

```
const f = (o : A | B) : string => {
  if (typeof o.x !== "undefined") {
    return o.x;
  }
  if (typeof o.y !== "undefined") {
    return o.y;
  }
  throw new Error("Unreachable code path");
};
```

to make it clear to Flow that the two cases where the properties exist are the only two cases where a string can be returned.

Comment: This is a very good answer because it gets to the root of the issue. Thanks!